# API for GeoLocation on Android tablet running Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7

Are there any APIs available that allow for access to Android tablet sensor information such as GPS from Windows 7? Any references or tutorials would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be able to run an application on Win7 that will access a remote Android machine and access its GPS data?If this is the case you're going to need to write an application or service in Android that would provide this information. The alternative would be API level access for foreign services requesting data from your device. Location data will also require a specific permission to be granted for your application, explicitly by the user, at install time. The documentation for the LocationManager in Android is here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html.